# Why are my Temporary ASP.NET Folders Empty?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

According to the MSDN, the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files" is supposed to contain precompiled ASP.NET files. Why is this directory empty on my development box (including x64) but not on my live server?  Is it caching it somewhere else?  FYI, I am using IIS Express 8.0. Is it dependent on IIS?